# A question on harmonic two-forms

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, differential-forms, hodge-theory

Let $(M^4,g)$ be a closed Riemannian four-manifold with $b_2^+>0$ and $b_2^->0$, is it possible to find two harmonic two-forms $\alpha\in H^2_+(M)$ and $\beta\in H^2_-(M)$, such that
\begin{equation*}
|\alpha(x)|^2=|\beta(x)|^2\quad\text{for all } x\in M ?
\end{equation*}
Thank you.

Comment: Here is a guess: If $\omega$ is a harmonic form then the square of its pointwise norm $|\omega|^2$ is a subharmonic function. (This is true if you consider harmonicity with respect to a flat metric.) By compactness of $M$, this subharmonic function will be constant. Then you obtain a positive answer to your question.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I am not sure, since we have the Weitzenbock formula for harmonic two-forms on four-manifolds, \begin{equation*} \frac{1}{2}\Delta|\omega|^2=|\nabla\omega|^2+\frac{R}{3}|\omega|^2-W(\omega, \omega).\end{equation*} If $|\omega|^2$ is constant, then we can get nice properties for the manifold.